# deleting a class generate garbage?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

(1)

```
class A:
    pass

del A
print "collect", gc.collect()   # collect 0
```

(2)

```
class A(object):
    pass

del A
print "collect", gc.collect()    # collect 6
```

Deleting a new style class generate garbage? Is there any circular reference in a new style class?

Comment: Well, on Python 3.5, Linux. **(1)** gives me `collect 5`, and **(2)** gives me `collect 0`.

Comment: In Python 2.7.3, Ubuntu Linux, (1) gives `collect 0` and (2) gives `collect 6`.

Comment: Keep in mind that garbage collection generally only comes into play when deallocating cyclic references.  In the majority of simple cases, storage is freed as soon as the last reference to an item is removed.

Comment: @KevinGuan Normally, in Python 3, (1) and (2) shouldn't have any semantic difference, as old-style classes are gone...

Comment: @glglgl Oops, I realized that I was running the code in bpython...but now the question is, when I run the code in Python Shell, they both give me `collect 6`...